# Ionic cross-platform (ios-Android) audio sharing

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, audio, ionic3

I'm using Ionic to create an app. In this app, there is the possibility to create a audio file. For ios there will be a .m4a file. For Android there is a .3gp file. These files are saved on a server. Other users can get these audio files and listen them. So far, so good.

The issue is when a ios user records an audio file and a android user wants to listen to this file. Are there Ionic users out there that succesfully made a cross-platform audio sharing app?